# Shortcut not created when Target exe name contains space in WIX

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, shortcut

I am getting an issue in creating the shortcut in Wix. When I give exe name or path  (without space) in shortcut target attribute then shortcut created.

But when I give exe name or path (with space) in shortcut target attribute then shortcut not created.

Below is working code (exe name without space).

```
     <DirectoryRef Id="StartupFolder">
      <Component Id="MyComponentId" Guid="*">
        <Shortcut Id="ApplicationStartMenuShortcut"
              Name="MyAppName"
            Description="MyApp Description"
             Target="[#MyTestApp.exe]"
             WorkingDirectory="MyAppDirectory"/>
```

and this below code is working (exe name with space).

```
    <DirectoryRef Id="StartupFolder">
      <Component Id="MyComponentId" Guid="*">
        <Shortcut Id="ApplicationStartMenuShortcut"
              Name="MyAppName"
            Description="MyApp Description"
             Target="[#My Test App.exe]"
             WorkingDirectory="MyAppDirectory"/>
```

SO just want to know that when I give exe name or path  (with space) in shortcut target attribute then the shortcut is created or not?

And if created then how can I do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target is just the property name, so it is not allowed to have spaces in it.
But you can have spaces in the shortcut name `Shortcut[@Name]` and in the file name `File[@Source]`.

So, in case your executable file has spaces in its name, you can do the following:

```
<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
        <Component Id="Component_MyAppExecutable" Guid="*">
            <File Id="File_ApplicationExecutable" Source="My Test App.exe" />
        </Component>

        <Component Id="MyComponentId" Guid="{B0A9F180-49C1-4059-B1D9-8EF0186D5C98}">
            <CreateFolder />

            <Shortcut Id="ApplicationStartMenuShortcut"
                      Name="My App Name"
                      Description="MyApp Description"
                      Target="[#File_ApplicationExecutable]"
                      WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" />
        </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

Note: The Guid attribute must be explicitly specified for a shortcut.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But just FYI, I was talking about the line   Target="[#MyTestApp.exe]" and   Target="[#My Test App.exe]". Here I used the name with space. I was not talking about the  Name="MyAppName".

Comment: Yes, but as I said, this is a property and spaces are not allowed. For more information, you can check this reference: [Restrictions on Property Names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371245.aspx)

Comment: Marlos, Thanks for letting me know that a "Target" is a property and spaces are not allowed in this.